# Python: What is the syntax for adding a command to a tkinter Listbox item?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, tkinter, filepath

below is my code for creating a tool that takes a file path, stores the value, and then opens the specific file path selected by the user.

Currently, I'm looking to take the user entry `mypathEntry` that is stored in the `mypathList` listbox after clicking the `Save` button and add a command to it. The command will open that selected file path. My current code returns an error message regarding `mypathList.add_command(command=Open)` stating that Listbox instance has no attribute 'add_command'.

**What is the syntax for adding a command to a listbox item?**

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

def Save():
    fp = mypathEntry.get()
    scribe = open('filepath.txt', 'w')
    scribe.write(fp)
    mypathEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    mypathList.insert(1, fp)

def Open():
    path = fp

menu = Menu(root)
##root.config(menu=menu)

##subMenu = Menu(menu)
##menu.add_cascade(label="Filepaths", menu=subMenu)
##subMenu.add_command(command=Save)

mypathLabel = Label(root, text="Copy and Paste your filepath here:")
mypathEntry = Entry(root, bg="black", fg="white", relief=SUNKEN)
mypathSaveButton = Button(root, text="Save Path", bg="black", fg="white", command=Save)

mypathList = Listbox(root, bg="black", fg="white")
mypathList.add_command(command=Open)


mypathLabel.pack()
mypathEntry.pack()
mypathSaveButton.pack()
mypathList.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [The Tkinter Listbox Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter Listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647735/tkinter-listbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this,
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm
The listbox item does not have a command option. So what you need to do instead is to bind an event to it. Here is a complete working example.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
class MainGui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.mypathLabel = Label(master, text="Copy and Paste your filepath here:")
        self.mypathEntry = Entry(master, bg="black", fg="white", relief=SUNKEN)
        self.mypathSaveButton = Button(master, text="Save Path", bg="black", fg="white", command=self.save_path)
        self.mypathList = Listbox(master, bg="black", fg="white")

        self.mypathLabel.pack()
        self.mypathEntry.pack()
        self.mypathSaveButton.pack()
        self.mypathList.pack()
        self.mypathList.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.open_path)

    def save_path(self):
        fp = self.mypathEntry.get()
        self.mypathEntry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.mypathList.insert(1, fp)

    def open_path(self, event):
        list_item = self.mypathList.curselection()
        fp = self.mypathList.get(list_item[0])
        print(fp)
        try:
            with open(fp, 'r') as result:
                print(result.read())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)    

MainGui(root)
root.mainloop()
```