# Getting Tkinter listbox item when hit Button-1

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

After creating a simple window/widget layout with Page (page.sourceforge.net)
I found that the listbox curselection() call returns the proper index when releasing Button-1.
When hit, it returns the previous index (the item which we just leave).

Becasue of some timer activities I'd like to get the clicked index at click-time, instead of release-time. Can somebody help me how could I do that? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a callback when a Tkinter Listbox selection is changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554805/getting-a-callback-when-a-tkinter-listbox-selection-is-changed)

Answer (score 1):

Bind to the event `<<ListboxSelect>>` instead of `<1>`, this event will fire after the current selection has been updated.

If you genuinely need for the binding to work literally on a press of the mouse button you will have to rearrange the order of the bind tags for the widget.