# python tkinter listbox event binding

Tags: python, listbox, widget, tkinter

I'm having trouble getting an event binding to work with python/tkinter. I'm simply trying to click and have the location printed, but every time I do this, "-1" is the result.

Here's my code

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter

class make_list(Tkinter.Listbox):

    def __init__(self,master, **kw):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.build_main_window(frame)

        kw['selectmode'] = Tkinter.SINGLE
        Tkinter.Listbox.__init__(self, master, kw)
        master.bind('<Button-1>', self.click_button)
        master.curIndex = None

    #display the clicked location
    def click_button(self, event):
        self.curIndex = self.nearest(event.x)
        print self.curIndex

    #display the window, calls the listbox
    def build_main_window(self, frame):
        self.build_listbox(frame)

    #listbox
    def build_listbox(self, frame):
        listbox = Listbox(frame)
        for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
            listbox.insert(END, item)    
        listbox.insert(END, "a list entry")
        listbox.pack()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tkinter.Tk()
    make_list(tk)
    tk.mainloop()
```

**updated code - I got rid of frame but I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting -1 for the first print statement in the function click_button**

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter

class make_list(Tkinter.Listbox):

    #display the clicked location
    def click_button(self, event):
        ##this block works
        w = event.widget
        index = int(w.curselection()[0])
        value = w.get(index)
        print value
        ##this doesn't
        self.curIndex = self.nearest(event.y)
        print self.curIndex
        self.curIndex = event.widget.nearest(event.y)
        print self.curIndex

    #display the window, calls the listbox
    def build_main_window(self):
        self.build_listbox()

    #listbox
    def build_listbox(self):
        listbox = Listbox()
        listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.click_button)
        for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
            listbox.insert(END, item)    
        listbox.insert(END, "a list entry")
        listbox.pack()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tkinter.Tk()
    start = make_list(tk)
    start.build_main_window()
    start.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by printing "the location"? Do you want the index of the item, the x/y coordinate, or the data that is currently selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listbox` nearest item is found by `y`, not `x`.

```
 self.nearest(event.x)     # wrong
 self.nearest(event.y)     # right
```

Update: I didn't notice the real problem first:

```
    listbox = Listbox(frame)
```

It's not the same listbox which you subclassed, it's another unrelated listbox. *Your* listbox (which *is* make_list) is empty, that's why it always returns -1 for nearest.

Perhaps subclassing a frame is a good idea (anyway, better than subclassing listbox and adding a frame with another listbox into it). Then you'll have to bind event on that *real* listbox which is not empty.

Quick way to see how it *will* work when fixed is to call `nearest` of a real listbox with `event.widget`:

```
self.curIndex = event.widget.nearest(event.y)
```

Comment: still displays -1 when I print curIndex (in the click_button method)

Comment: @user1104854 explained one more problem.

Comment: adding the code you suggested displays the correct position.  Consdiering I'm still very new to this, I'm sure I could figure this out, but I'd like to know the best practice for this situation so I don't run into trouble in the future from sloppy code. Can you please give me some advice on what you would change?

Comment: Sorry, I'm able to answer Tkinter questions just because I'm a long-time user of TCL/TK, and problems and solutions are sometimes directly translatable. But "I would just use TCL instead" is not a good kind of answer for you here. That said, I would avoid subclassing Tkinter things at all when I'm not designing a *reusable* widget: if it's my application, I wouldn't make it inherit from Listbox or anything. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: I updated my code above. Do you mind taking a look? I got rid of frame but it's still not working. Are you suggesting to not even bind to master, just use self?

Comment: You still have two listboxes (one that you build and another that you inherit from), and you still use the wrong one for `nearest`. Binding to master is wrong (it kinda works because each toplevel's widget has toplevel's name among their bindtags), but binding to self won't work with your current code (because self has no elements). (maybe you'd save your built listbox to self.listbox, and bind to self.listbox too?)

Comment: so if I'm not supposed to bind with self or master, what do I bind to?

Comment: I recommend binding to `listbox` that you build in `build_listbox` (that's actually gets items)

Comment: I updated my edit and restructured it. It's outputting 0 now, do you mind taking a look?

Comment: `<<ListboxSelect>>` event has no coordinates (it may be unrelated to mouse at all)

Answer (score 6):

In the comments of an answer you ask for the best practice. The best practice is to bind to `<<ListboxSelect>>` which will fire immediately after the item is selected in the listbox.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12936031/7432) to a similar question has an example.

Comment: I updated my edit above. I tried doing what you suggested but I'm getting 0 as the output, mind taking a look?

Comment: @user1104854: There are two problems. One is that you're asking for self.nearest(), but self is not the widget that has the data, and is not the widget that you click on. You have a very weird bit of code where you have a listbox embedded in a listbox. Also, I dont' think `<<ListboxSelect>>` sets `event.x` and `event.y`. The event doesn't represent a click, the event represents "the current item has changed" which may not always have an x and a y (ie: if you use the keyboard to change the current selection). `event.widget.curselection()` is what you should use.