# Python / Tkinter listbox troubles

Tags: python, events, listbox, widget, tkinter

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467604/python-tkinter-listbox-event-binding) and I was advised to restructure the code. It's now different enough that I feel it justifies asking a new question.

Anyway, I'm trying to add drag/drop functionality to a listbox, but I figured a good first step would be to get the event binding working in the first place. Currently, when I click on the list I get the following error upon clicking the listbox. The listbox window appears, but when I click it the error occurs.

```
 "AttributeError: make_list instance has no attribute 'nearest'.
```

Also, when I print listbox in the build_listbox method, the following decimal is printed .40720520L. Shouldn't this print the values in the listbox? Afterall, it's in the same method. Is the listbox not being created properly?

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter

class make_list:

    def move_mouse(self, event):
        self.curIndex = event.nearest(event.y)
        print self.curIndex

    def click_button(self, event):
        w= event.widget
        self.curIndex = int(w.curselection()[0])
        #print self.curIndex
        value = w.get(self.curIndex)
        print value

    def build_main_window(self):
        self.build_listbox()

    def build_listbox(self):
        listbox = Listbox()
        listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.click_button)
        listbox.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_mouse)
        for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
            listbox.insert(END, item)    
        listbox.insert(END, "a list entry")
        listbox.pack()
        print listbox
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = make_list()
    start.build_main_window()
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback so we know which line is generating the exception?

Comment: Actually you're getting an `AttributeError: Event instance has no attribute 'nearest'` on the first line in the `move_mouse()` definition. That's because the `event` object doesn't have a `nearest` method function  attribute.

Comment: @martineau, what do I change this to? I apologize, I'm new to tkinter and python in general

Comment: BTW, the PEP 8 naming convention for classes is `CapCase` so `make_list` should be `MakeList`.

Comment: `ListBox` objects have a `curselection()` method which returns the line numbers of the selected element(s) which is what you should be using. I suggest you spend some time reading one of the many `Tkinter` [tutorials](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Python+tutorial/Part+III+Python+Library+and+Extension+Modules/Chapter+16.+Tkinter+GUIs/16.9+Tkinter+Events/) that exist on the web and in various books.

Comment: [Here's](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Python+tutorial/Part+III+Python+Library+and+Extension+Modules/Chapter+16.+Tkinter+GUIs/16.2+Widget+Fundamentals/) a better example -- search for "Listbox" on the page.

Comment: @martineau I updated for curselection, but I'm still getting that strange decimal when I try to print my list. Any idea what's going on with that?

Comment: If you mean from the `print listbox` it's because `listbox` is an instance of a `ListBox` widget not an instance of a `list` -- and so it doesn't print like one. If you want to get and print what's listed in it then you'd need to do something like `print listbox.listvariable.get()` BTW, [here's](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html) another good Tkinter reference.

Comment: @martineau I can print listbox.size() and get the correct result but when I try to print listbox.get() I receive an error. If I try listbox.get(Tkinter.Listbox) I also receive an error. I also tried listbox.curselection() and it just shows an empty set of parenthesis

Comment: `listbox.size()` works because `size()` is one of the methods `ListBox` instances _do_ have (see the linked reference in my last response). As for the `listbox`'s contents, what I said to use was `listbox.listvariable.get()`, which is not either of the two things you said you tried -- so I'm not surprised.

Comment: @martineau I did try that, I guess I forgot to include that in the list of things I tried. It gives the following error "Listbox instance has no attribute 'listvariable'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. `listvariable` is widget option not an attribute, so retrieving its current value is done with `listbox.cget('listvariable')` -- however, for unknown reasons, that returns an empty string. What does work is `listbox.get(0, END)` which returns the tuple `('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'a list entry')`. BTW, the `ListBox` instance created in `build_listbox()` is stored in the local variable `listbox` and will automatically be deleted when the function returns -- so I suggest you instead (or also) assign the value to `self.listbox` to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! You saved me a bunch of frustration.

Comment: Good. I suspect `listbox.cget('listvariable')` not working right is a bug -- and not the first one I've encountered with `Tkinter`.

Comment: I also think you might want something like `self.curIndex = self.listbox.nearest(event.y)` in `move_mouse()`.

Comment: Changed to what you suggested in move_mouse(), works great! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The value you get when you do a `print` on a Tkinter widget is largely irrelevant to the user, it is merely the name of a `Tcl` variable that was created for you.

Now, since apparently your code is working (by quickly going through the comments in the question), I would suggest doing the drag & drop functionality in a different manner. For instance, if we had a list of values that was associated to the values in the `Listbox`, then it would be much easier to do the task if we could update this list and then it would reflect upon the `Listbox` display, right ? Too bad we don't have such thing in Python, but for the moment consider the following code:

```
import Tkinter

def list_click(event):
    w = event.widget
    index = w.nearest(event.y)
    w._selection = index

def list_motion(event):
    w = event.widget
    if w._selection is None:
        return
    index = w.curselection()[0]
    w._var.swap(index, w._selection)
    w._selection = index

def list_clear(event):
    event.widget._selection = None

root = Tkinter.Tk()

v = ListVar(values=('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'))
v.append('a list entry')

listbox = Tkinter.Listbox(listvar=v)
listbox.pack()

listbox._selection = None
listbox._var = v
listbox.bind('<1>', list_click)
listbox.bind('<B1-Motion>', list_motion)
listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', list_clear)

root.mainloop()
```

This code works in the following manner: when a mouse click happens in the listbox it marks the nearest item as "selected", when you move the mouse it swaps the items and update the selection, when you release the mouse button it clears the selection. What is missing is this `ListVar` thing then. Here it is:

```
class ListVar(Tkinter.Variable):
    def __init__(self, master=None, name=None, **kwargs):
        Tkinter.Variable.__init__(self, master, kwargs.get('values'), name)

    def set(self, values):
        self._tk.call('set', self._name, values)

    def set_index(self, index, value):
        self._tk.call('lset', self._name, index, value)

    def get_index(self, index):
        return self._tk.eval('lindex $%s %d' % (self._name, index))

    def get(self, start=None, end=None):
        if start is None and end is None:
            res = self._tk.eval('lrange $%s 0 end' % self._name)
        elif end is None:
            res = self._tk.eval('lrange $%s %d end' % (self._name, start))
        else:
            res = self._tk.eval('lrange $%s %d %d' % (self._name, start, end))
        return self._tk.splitlist(res)

    def swap(self, a, b):
        if a != b:
            tmp = self.get_index(a)
            self.set_index(a, self.get_index(b))
            self.set_index(b, tmp)

    def append(self, value):
        self._tk.eval('lappend %s {%s}' % (self._name, value))
```

It is very rough, will fail if you pass a value like "hello{", etc. This can be improved in many ways.