# Unexpected behavior with Tkinter and two Listboxes bound to ListboxSelect event

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I’ve encountered an unusual problem in a script that I’m working on. The program is written in Python3/Tkinter. It initializes two Listboxes, wrapped in two separate Frames, and according to the user’s commands displays either one or the other. An exception arises when the user selects on one of the items in the first Listbox, then decides to change screen and selects an item in the second frame.

I’ve created a sample code (below), to replicate the problem. With this code, during runtime, clicking on one item in the first Listbox (white background) makes the second Listbox appear (orange background). Also, the first object is “unpacked” and thus the user should no longer be able to interact with it. Finally, clicking on an item in the second Listbox, raises an IndexError in the “on_select_1” method from the first object. Why would that method execute after that event?? I’m well aware of my limits as a programmer, but I’m pretty sure this is not what is supposed to happen.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Listbox1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.lb1 = tk.Listbox(self)
        for i in ["item 1.1", "item 1.2", "item 1.3", "item 1.4"]:
            self.lb1.insert(tk.END, i)
        self.lb1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_select_1)
        self.lb1.pack()

    def on_select_1(self, *args):
        try:
            print("item {} selected in listbox 1".format(self.lb1.curselection()[0]))
        except IndexError:
            print("IndexError raised in method 'on_select_1'")

        self.master.switch()


class Listbox2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.lb2 = tk.Listbox(self, bg='orange')
        for i in ["item 2.1", "item 2.2", "item 2.3", "item 2.4"]:
            self.lb2.insert(tk.END, i)
        self.lb2.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_select_2)
        self.lb2.pack()

    def on_select_2(self, *args):
        print("item {} selected in listbox 2".format(self.lb2.curselection()[0]))


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.lb1_frame = Listbox1(self)
        self.lb2_frame = Listbox2(self)
        self.lb1_frame.pack()

    def switch(self):
        self.lb1_frame.pack_forget()
        self.lb2_frame.pack()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? An index out of bounds error is very self-explanatory. Have you examined what `self.lbl.curselection()` returns before trying to pull an item out of it? It's probably not what you think it is.

Comment: Hi Brian, respectfully, I think you are missing the point... the index out of bound is indeed easy to catch, what it's not self-explanatory is why would the second Listbox object call the method in the first Listbox. The binding is done correctly, so picking an item in the second listbox should just run it's own "on_select_2" method. How can it end up calling the "on_select_1" method in another object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, tkinter only allows one widget to hold the selection at a time. Thus, when you select something in your second listbox, the item selected in the first listbox is deselected. That causes your function to be called. When this happens, `self.lb1.curselection()[0])` throws an error because the selection is empty.

A simple solution that allows the selection to remain unchanged in the first listbox when you select something in the second listbox is to set the `exportselection` option to `False` for both listboxes.

```
self.lb1 = tk.Listbox(self, exportselection=False)
...
self.lb2 = tk.Listbox(self, bg='orange', exportselection=False)
```

Comment: Hi @Bryan Oakley, is this "default" only in certain versions of tkinter / python? How comes the error does not arise in all versions / conditions where the exact same code is used?

Comment: @R4PH43L: AFAIK this has not changed in the last decade or two, and is the same on all platforms. I don't currently have a windows box that I can test on so I can't say definitively that this behavior is the same on modern versions of windows. It would surprise me if it were different.

Comment: Yes.. this fixes the problem. Thank you! In fact there was something reported on effbot.org [link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm). I came across that article yesterday during my research, but didn't connect the dots. Sorry.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I can't reproduce the error on Win7 running either python35-33 / python27.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14481718/4198514) respective the comment on it from @BryanOakley:

> The event doesn't represent a click, the event represents "the current item has changed" which may not always have an x and a y (ie: if you use the keyboard to change the current selection). event.widget.curselection() is what you should use.

So if the Listbox is destroyed, the new selection is as per the [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html)

> **.curselection()**
>
>     Returns a tuple containing the line numbers of the selected element or elements, counting from 0. If nothing is selected, returns an empty tuple. .

Therefore you get the IndexError as `self.lb1.curselection()==()`, which results in `()[0]`.

Comment: ... but why would that method execute? It is out of its scope, isn't it? I understand that the "curseletcion()" of the first listbox returns None, but when that happens my second object shouldn't call the curselection() of the first object.

Comment: As you unpack the listbox, what is the curselection of it?

Comment: Right after the `pack_forget()`, the `curselection()[0]` returns the index value of whichever item I had picked in the first listbox (that triggers the switch method to make the second listbox appear).

Comment: Can you tell us something about your environment? I cannot reproduce the error in python35-33 nor in python27. (both on windows)

Comment: I'm working on Win10, the interpreter is Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

This problem definitely exists in Python 3.8 on Windows 10 and changing even one of my two list boxes to `export=FALSE` fixed the problem.