# Python - Tkinter.Listbox <<ListboxSelect>> does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I've got 2 Listboxes in my program, and I'm trying to take currently selected item. In setsList everything works fine but for appsList it does not. I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

**Here are functions for getting selected item:**

```
def selectSet(evt):
    print("Called Select Set")
    global activeSetApps
    global activeSet
    activeSetApps.clear()
    activeSet = str(setsList.get(setsList.curselection()))
    dir = "sets/"+str(activeSet)+".txt"
    f = open(dir, "r")
    activeSetApps = f.read().split("\n")
    printApps()
    f.close()
def appSelect(evt):
    print("Called Select App")
    global activeSetApps
    global activeApp
    activeApp = str(appsList.get(appsList.curselection()))
    print(activeApp)
```

**And here are Listbox definitions**

```
setsList = tk.Listbox(appSetList)
appsList = tk.Listbox(appsInSet)
setsList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', selectSet)
appsList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', appSelect)
setsList.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.9, rely=0.1)
appsList.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.9, rely=0.1)
```

When I run my code and select something from the setsList it work fine and prints:

```
Called Select Set
```

But when I select something from appsList it prints:

```
Called Select App
Ehh.PNG
Called Select Set
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\Git\App-runner\app-runner.py", line 37, in selectSet
    activeSet = str(setsList.get(setsList.curselection()))
  File "C:\Users\mateu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2798, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first)
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
```

Comment: Relevant: [unexpected-behavior-with-two-listboxes-bound-to-listboxsel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991760)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use `appsList.get(tk.ANCHOR)` instead of `appsList.get(appsList.curselection())`.  Same for `setsList`.