# Python and Listbox (GUI)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have constructed a listbox using tkinter
Now I want the user to click on an item in the listbox that creates a variable with the selection.

```
listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', get_list)

def get_list(event):
    index = listbox.curselection()[0]
    seltext = listbox.get(index)
    print(seltext)
```

This properly prints out the selection. However, I am unable to get the "seltext" out of the function and able to use it later in the code. Someone recommended the get_list(event) however I don't know where event came from. Appreciate the help

EDIT:

```
   for f in filename:
                with open(f) as file_selection:
                    for line in file_selection:
                        Man_list = (line.split(',')[1])

                        listbox.insert(END, Man_list)

                file_selection.close()



        def get_list(event):
            global seltext
            # get selected line index
            index = listbox.curselection()[0]
            # get th e line's text
            global seltext
            seltext = listbox.get(index)



        # left mouse click on a list item to display selection
        listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', get_list)
```

Comment: Event handlers are not built to return values. Have you not tried making a global variable or a class property?

Comment: @Hobbes I am fairly new to Python so I really don't have an idea what those are. Are you able to help me?

Comment: What is the best way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12936031/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you! Does this return the selected item back to the main program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with how you are structuring your code more than anything. Event handlers are not built to return values. Use a global variable or class property to retrieve and store the value. A global variable can be set like so:

```
from Tkinter import *

def get_list(event):
    global seltext
    index = listbox.curselection()[0]
    seltext = listbox.get(index)

root = Tk()
listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()
listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', get_list)

for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

seltext = None

root.mainloop()
```

But a class property is the better option. Your Tkinter application should be modular to ensure everything is easily accessible and prevent problems like this. You can set variables to `self` and access them later that way.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        listbox = Listbox(self)
        listbox.pack()
        listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.get_list)

        for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
            listbox.insert(END, item)

        self.listbox = listbox # make listbox a class property so it
                               # can be accessed anywhere within the class

    def get_list(self, event):
        index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]
        self.seltext = self.listbox.get(index) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: for the first one, how would you get seltext out of the function?

Comment: still unable to have print(seltext) outside of the function

Comment: My entire answer covers how you would transfer a variable to another scope without the use of a return statement. You need to be more clear with what issue you are running into, and maybe post more code in the original post. It's hard to diagnose a scope issue without more information.

Comment: Your first code: you have seltext = None....I want this seltext to be equal to what was clicked. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `seltext = None` is declaring that the variable exists. When the user clicks and releases their mouse button on a listbox value, the code enters `get_list(event)`. Within `get_list(event)` a [global variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) is called and set to the value that the user selected. From this point on in the program, `seltext` will refer to the value selected until changed.

Comment: Later in the program if you do print(seltext) the following error message occurs

Comment: NameError: name 'seltext' is not defined

Comment: It completely depends on where you are trying to print `seltext`. You would need to declare `global seltext` at the top of any function that uses it. Once again, it is very difficult to diagnose scope issues without more code. These are two ways that you can access a variable outside of a function without the use of a return statement. It is up to you to understand the base concepts and modify them to fit your specific code.

Comment: I have attached the code above. Let me know if you can help out I really appreciate it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120989/discussion-between-alex-weinstein-and-hobbes).