# Binding events / commands to items in a listbox (with a scrollbar)

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am making a program in which any amount of users can be made, and to select one, you have to click on their name, which is contained in a scrollable listbox. **Is there any way (bindings or otherwise) to have a command be executed upon clicking different items in the listbox?**

Comment: ok there's the question now, i kinda forgot to put it

Comment: Please provide a basic example of the listbox lacking the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
def onselect(evt):
# Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()
w = evt.widget
index = int(w.curselection()[0])
value = w.get(index)
print 'You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value)

lb = Listbox(frame, name='lb')
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)
```

I took this in the comments of the post [Getting a callback when a Tkinter Listbox selection is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554805/getting-a-callback-when-a-tkinter-listbox-selection-is-changed), which contained the answer above.