# How can I update a tkinter Label with every new selection in Listbox?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I would like the labels on the right side to update when a name in the list box is selected. When a new name in the list is selected, the name label on the right remains the same.

I tried `name_list.index(ACTIVE)` directly within student_name.set() as `student_name.set(students_list[name_list.index(ACTIVE)].get_name())`.  I'm afraid that it is just using index 0 and not even using active selection.

```
from tkinter import *

# Defining Student class
class Student:

  def __init__(self, name, instrument=""):
    self.name = name
    self.instrument = instrument

  def get_name(self):
    return self.name

  def get_instrument(self):
    return self.instrument

# Creating Student objects and list
s1 = Student("Seth", "Trumpet")
s2 = Student("Cassie", "Flute")
s3 = Student("Cody", "Guitar")
students_list = [s1, s2, s3]

# GUI created
def make_window():
  rootWindow = Tk()
  rootWindow.title("Instructor Database Application")
  rootWindow.grid()

  frame0 = Frame(rootWindow)
  frame0.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)

  name_list = Listbox(frame0, height=10)
  name_list.grid(column=0, row=0)
  for Student in students_list:
    name_list.insert(END, Student.get_name())

  frame1 = Frame(rootWindow)
  frame1.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)

  student_index = name_list.index(ACTIVE)
  student_name = StringVar()
  student_name.set(students_list[student_index].get_name())

  name_label = Label(frame1, textvariable=student_name)
  name_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

  instrument_label = Label(frame1, text="Instrument")
  instrument_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

  return rootWindow

def main():
  app = make_window()
  app.mainloop()

main()
```

The program begins with the first name and is unable to change. Any advice?

Comment: all code before `mainloop` is excuted even before you see window - and it is executed only once. You have to bind to list function which will be executed everytime you select element on list and this function has to change label.

Comment: @furas Okay. I am understanding the concept. Do you have any suggestions on where or how should I call this function when I make a new selection? I'm not exactly sure how a new selection is detected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554805/getting-a-callback-when-a-tkinter-listbox-selection-is-changed Seems a bit like a work-around but I think this will serve. Thanks

Comment: you have example in my answer. It shows how to bind function which can change value when you select new element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind function to `listbox` which will be executed when you change selection. And this function has to change text in label

```
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', my_function)
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- function ---

def on_selection(event):
    # here you can get selected element
    print('previous:', listbox.get('active'))
    print(' current:', listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

    # or using `event`

    #print('event:', event)
    #print('widget:', event.widget)
    print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
    print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))

    lbl['text'] = "Seleced: " + listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
    print('---')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert(1, 'Hello 1')
listbox.insert(2, 'Hello 2')
listbox.insert(3, 'Hello 3')
listbox.insert(4, 'Hello 4')
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)

lbl = tk.Label(root, text='?')
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: more examples for tkinter (and other python's modules) on GitHub: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter