# Pop up specific files in Listbox of Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I made tiny a program finding files containing specific text input from User. But, now it is only possible to find .txt files.

As you can see, I found some files and listed them on the Listbox. Now, I want to open one of them by clicking it. How should I implement this feature? I used the subprocess.popen before to pop up files but I don't know how to open them in Listbox using Tkinter.

[Enter image description here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evzVe.png)

Comment: Use the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event generated when a selection is made. You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554805/getting-a-callback-when-a-tkinter-listbox-selection-is-changed) for details.

Comment: Solved with <<ListboxSelect>>.Thank you